# Flutter integration with freshchat , on initialization it should display helpcenter

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-getx, freshdesk, freshchat

I integrated flutter with fresh_chat sdk , i want to use the helpcenter widget on click of a button, i am having options like freshchat.showConversations() and freshchat.showFAQ() but i am not able to find freshchat helpcenter widget.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
  Freshchat.showFAQs();
```

use following for custom changes

```
                     Freshchat.showFAQ(
                        showContactUsOnFaqScreens: true,
                        showContactUsOnAppBar: true,
                        showFaqCategoriesAsGrid: true,
                        showContactUsOnFaqNotHelpful: true);
                    });
```

Looks like FreshchatHelpCenter has been removed from the latest version

its previous implementation was

```
  FreshchatHelpCenter.show(
          helpCenterConfig: HelpCenterConfig(
            "CATEGORY_ID",
            "FILTER_ID",
          ),
        );
```

Comment: I tried Freshchat.showFAQ()  its working fine showing me details of FAQs but i want the complete help center widget , how to achieve that ? or i can code the ui and use specific functions to be called for eg. on click of FAQ it will call Freshchat.showFAQ() , Any idea?

Comment: yes, create UI and according to your use, you can make changes.


Freshchat.showFAQ(
                            showContactUsOnFaqScreens: true,
                            showContactUsOnAppBar: true,
                            showFaqCategoriesAsGrid: true,
                            showContactUsOnFaqNotHelpful: true);
                      });